# React does not render on the page

Tags: gruntjs, reactjs, browserify

I'm using the example from the react (0.14.2) blog:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');

var MyComponent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return <div>Hello World</div>;
  }
});

console.info('reactdom render');
ReactDOM.render(<MyComponent />, document.getElementById('whoopidoo'));
```

I compile it with grunt:

```
browserify: {
    options: {
        transform: [
            ['babelify', {
                loose: 'all'
            }]
        ]
    },
```

And include the script in an html page:

```
<script src="1_basic_minimal.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

But the page is just blank, no errors, absolutely nothing. Is my compiling wrong perhaps?

**edit**
contents of file:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({},{},[]);
```

Comment: Do you see `reactdom render` in the console?

Comment: @FelixKling no nothing

Comment: Then the script is probably not even loaded / executed. Check the network tab whether `1_basic_minimal.js` is loaded.

Comment: @FelixKling the file is loaded fine, but the js file is probably wrong, doesn't seem like any of my code is in the file.